# iOS Google analytics not tracking App speed

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am trying to track my app speed using Google analytics but i could not see anything under app speed in the website. But i could see other parameters like events,crashes and exceptions.Following is the code what i am using to send event timing.

```
  self.endDate=[NSDate date];
  double timeDiff=[_startDate timeIntervalSinceDate:_endDate];
  NSLog(@"timeDiff----%f",timeDiff);
  if([[[GAI sharedInstance]defaultTracker] sendTimingWithCategory:category withValue:timeDiff withName:@"LoadTime" withLabel:category])
  {
    NSLog(@"Succesfully sent load time to GA");
  }
```

**Following is the message printed in the console.
GoogleAnalytics 2.0b4 -[GAIDispatcher dispatchComplete:withStartTime:withRetryNumber:withResponse:withData:withError:] (GAIDispatcher.m:415) DEBUG: Successfully dispatched hit /GAIHit/p479 (0 retries).**
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the official docs the [example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/usertimings) uses a different method than the one you are using here.

```
- (void)onLoad:(NSTimeInterval *)loadTime {
    [tracker sendTimingWithVariableCategory:@"resources"
                            withTimeInterval:loadTime
                                    withName:@"high scores"
                                   withLabel:nil];
    ... // The rest of your onLoad: code.
}
```

Things to check:

- Make sure you are using the latest version of the [SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources).
- Make sure you cast the loadTime to NSTimeInterval, the SDK is kinda strict with types.

Comment: Hi Eduardo, Thanks for your answer. I will work on it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Google have it wrong in doc. 
NSTimeInterval is double, their SDK wants integer. Example on their web site is misleading.

```
- (void)onLoad:(NSTimeInterval *)loadTime {

    NSNumber* timeInterval = [NSNumber numberWithInt:((int) (loadTime * 1000))];
    [tracker sendTimingWithVariableCategory:@"resources"
                            withTimeInterval:timeInterval
                                    withName:@"high scores"
                                   withLabel:nil];
    ... // The rest of your onLoad: code.
}
```